# find out what class is affecting a particular element

Tags: css, firefox, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to see exactly which declaration is affecting an element. Rather than looking at a million properties in the Firebug inspector, where depending on how many classes something is assigned may contain a lot of declarations that are lower precedence and therefore not applied. It can get lengthy to find which particular declaration is in fact affecting your element. I see long ignored declarations like this:

ul {

      <strike>color: green;</strike>

}

"Computed style" will show you the end result of all the hierarchies, but not where the style derives from. Maybe I'm missing something simple. Thanks much!

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/unarap/1/edit)

Edit:
I've heard that I should be able to expand attributes in the Computed tag, however I don't see where that option is available. I can see that the font-size is 13.333px, but no option to see where that's coming from.

[image: computed tab]

Comment: (Firebug) The HTML tab should have a side window on the right that shows all the styles affecting whatever element you select.  You can even disable/alter the attributes and see how the page will be affected.  Whichever attribute is closest to the top should be the one being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Firebug select the element and then click on the 'Computed' tab (when viewing the HTML frame). Here you will see a list of CSS properties than can be expanded to show the location of the relevant CSS.

Comment: That's odd you might try updating Firefox or reinstalling Firebug, but you should see expand/contract icons next to individual properties (width, height, etc.) that allow you to see the specific line in the CSS tree that is applying its style.

Comment: Not only do I have the icons, but clicking anywhere on the line displaying the property seems to toggle the expanded view. Perhaps try clicking on the text itself to see if it toggles that?

Comment: Okay. I will do. What version of firefox/bug do you have? Thanks!

Comment: I reported my PC setup. I did verify the expand/collapse functionality on the iMac at my office. I'd have to report those versions tomorrow.

Comment: I just downloaded on an old ThinkPad I have. It is completely as you describe. I wonder why it is different on my mac.

Comment: @thomas I've got Fx 20.0 and Firebug 1.11.2 on my Mac.

Comment: incomprehensible to me why it would say it's up to date. But you were right. I was 8 versions behind! I usually use chrome, so I didn't even notice. Thanks so much!

Comment: So the feature to expand/collpse and list different rules for the same property in Computed tab is removed in the latest Firefox/Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

The [*Computed* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Computed_Side_Panel) can give you this info.

Note that it just shows the CSS trace - i.e. the styles that are affecting a specific CSS property - for those properties, which are actually changed by the CSS rules of your stylesheet. Though it can display all computed values for an element. To hide the unchanged ones you can uncheck the option *Show User Agent CSS*.

Also please ensure that you have a current version of Firefox installed (current stable is 20.0.1). Firebug internally uses some APIs for the style tracing, which are just available on newer versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome DevTools there is 'computed style' panel which shows you the list of styles for an element property and their locations. For example see the screenshot for text-decoration property.

[image: screenshot]